# Phantom Input When Running Green Hills Debugger

Tags: c++, rtos, greenhills

I'm running on a Marvell Monahans PXA320 under Green Hills INTEGRITY 5.0.10. I'm using MULTI 4.2.3 for development. I'm using an RTSERV connection for debugging, I've been asked to take over a menu-driven program.

I've noticed that if I halt the program (to modify breakpoints) and then resume it, the task gets into an infinite loop displaying the menu in the debugger I/O tab. After each instance of the menu that gets printed, it says that I have made an illegal selection. So, some input is apparently being fed into the task as if I had typed it in (and this input obviously corresponds to an invalid menu selection). I do not see on the display what this phantom input is.

Is there anything I can do to prevent a halt / resume from screwing up the I/O?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: What's driving your OS timer tick?

Comment: Does the menu normally go over a serial port?  Can you configure the debugger to go ahead and let it go over the serial port?  And if so, what happens then?  Same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that getc() (or your equivalent) is returning -1.  This can happen if your input buffers overflowed as a result of halting the application.  I/O keeps flowing while the application is halted...

It is generally not a good idea to halt the program when debugging with INTEGRITY.  You're generally better off to attach the debugger to a single thread (something idle or infrequently used), set an "any-task" breakpoint in that thread, then resume the thread. (Don't close the window! Doing so will delete the breakpoint.)  You'll see a "DebugBrk" status on the thread that hits the breakpoint -- then you can double-click and attach to that specific thread.

Following that alternate procedure should (hopefully!) prevent the I/O error.